# how to show file in a template - django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to show an uploaded file :

```
{% for post in posts %}
       <img src="{{post.image.url}}">    
       <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
       <button type="button" class="btn view-project-btn">view more</button>
       <div class="item-details">
           <div class="description">
                 <p>{{post.description}}</p>
           </div>
           <div class="info">
                <ul>
                    <li>created - <span>{{post.date_creation}}</span></li>
                    <li>le theme de recherche -<span>{{post.sous_titre}}</span></li>
                    {{post.body|safe}}
                   
                    <iframe src="{{post.file.url}}" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
                </ul>
              ....                
{% endfor %}
```

this is my views

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request,'base/index.html',context)
```

but it doesn't work **it works for imagefield {{example.image.url}}**, this is the attribute in my model `file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to="sources")`

thanks for your help and suggestions

the error :
[image]

Not Found: /sources/file1.pdf

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('post.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in my settings

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') 
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: try adding your template & views.py file

Comment: add your models to

Answer (score 0):

here is the issue in your views your are posts in for calling the file but u are using post instead of posts

```
def home(request):
    post = Post.objects.filter(active=True)
    context = {'posts':post}
    return render(request,'base/index.html',context)
```

change your view and you are good to go
or change your html code it's totaly upto you

add this in your mainprojects urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

try this

```
<embed
    src="{{post.file.url}}"
    type="application/pdf"
    frameBorder="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    height="500px"
    width="100%"
></embed>
```

Comment: Not Found: /sources/file1.pdf this is the error  (

Comment: add your main projects urls.py

Comment: did you add your statcfiles and media file  urls

Comment: ```<iframe src="{{post.file.url}}" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>``` is this right ?

Comment: @marc-stupid if is still doesnt work add the screenshot of your workin directory

Comment: I don't get any error in my working directory everything is fine I can see that I get the file .......but still I can't see the pdf in my template, I used ```{% static 'media/sources/pdf.pdf'%}``` (it's an example)and it shows the pdf but using ```{{post.file.url}}``` doesn't show anything in my HTML page .....I don't know where is the problem,

Comment: acc to you settings.py file path has to static/images/sources/pdf.pdf

Comment: @marc-stupid add your models.py  and working directory screenshot so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

edit media root

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/images')
```

this is wrong, you can't have media root in static root

remove static/ and try it again

Comment: no wrong .... it will not work .. even that I just tried nd doesn't work I can't see the pictures too